# css remove dotted line around logo

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have the following html:

```
<div class='navbar'>
    <div class='home'>
       <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='#';"><i class="fa fa-home">
    </i></button>
...
```

with this css:

```
.navbar.home.btn {
font-size: 20px;    
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
}

.navbar a:hover, #dropdwn:hover #dropdwn_btn, .navbar .home:hover .btn{
background-color: red;
transition: 0.5s;
}
```

question: when I focus this btn, there is a small dotted line around it, even if I do

```
.navbar.home.btn:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

it still shows up, how can I get rid of it ?

You can see the  button and the dotted line around it when focused in the attached picture.

thx in advance.

Comment: first question is solved, I had to just add a link into onlick method. Further I just added cursor: pointer => the whole div was already clickable, it just didnt work because of missing link

Comment: the question with the dotted line is still opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY spesific to `icon`**

```
   .navbar.home.btn:focus i{
    border: none;
    }
```

```css
.navbar.home.btn {
font-size: 20px;    
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
}

.navbar a:hover, #dropdwn:hover #dropdwn_btn, .navbar .home:hover .btn{
background-color: red;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.btn:focus i{
    outline: none;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class='navbar'>
    <div class='home'>
       <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='#';"><i class="fa fa-home">
    </i></button>
```

Comment: So try `:active` and `:focus`

Comment: can you create fiddle because when i run it i see no dots

Comment: hooo try: .navbar.home.btn:focus i{...}

Comment: do you have any link to your site

Comment: try to use `!important`: `.btn:focus i{
    outline: none!important;
    border:none!important;
}`

Comment: in the editor , when pressing the button, ur code seems working, there is no dotted line, I am using google chrome, maybe that is why ??

Comment: no i use goole too please add `!important` as i said above to prevent ovrreide

Comment: try to use `!important`: `.btn:focus i{ outline: none!important; border:none!important; }`

Comment: in my browser it still shows up, I tried now this thing on my safari browser, there it works, I rly guess it is sth about browser. I used ur code with important, ty for that one, learned sth new

Comment: Thx for ur help mate, u fixed the issue, eventhough it is still poppign up on some browsers

Comment: happy to help :) I really do not know why ...`!important` must fix you issuse

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce the dotted line by using your code.

There must be another css rule that's causing it, but without seeing all your code, there's no way to know. Can you try disabling your css files in turn to figure out what's causing it?

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzzMKj - it has the same code as your question, but no dotted line

Comment: Hi Sam, I still don't see any dotted line. Is it a browser-specific issue? I'm using Chrome

Comment: seems like browser specific issue, tried it now on multiple browsers, on some it is working, on some not

Comment: which browsers have the issue?

Comment: with the solution of בני מלכה, only firefox has this issue now

Comment: Do you have the latest version of firefox? There's still no dotted line in mine

Comment: no I dont have the current version of firefox, just installed it and in the most up to date version it works too, u are right, still would be interesting to know what I would have to adjust to make it runnin even on older version of firefox

Comment: btw, the dotted line is shown only when u press that btn (and hold it)